# Drawing a diagram of a three-cycle

Tags: diagrams

How to draw this kind of circle on LaTeX? [image]

Comment: Where would this go? Text? Figure? A bit of context would help because there can be several solutions and they are not all equally applicable.

Comment: I would typically use [xy-pic](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xymatrix) for that, but I'm not sure whether or not it is the best solution in this particular case. Let's say I'm sure it'd work with limited efforts, but not 100% sure it's optimal. Or go for tikz, but I'm even less comfortable with tikz.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For a true circular shape, use `arc`s instead of the `to` path.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,scale=.7]
   \node (i) at (90:1cm)  {$i$};
   \node (j) at (-30:1cm) {$j$};
   \node (k) at (210:1cm) {$k$};

   \draw (70:1cm)  arc (70:-10:1cm);
   \draw (-50:1cm) arc (-50:-130:1cm);
   \draw (190:1cm) arc (190:110:1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A more compact form using `\foreach` can be like this (with the same result as above):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,scale=.7] 
  \foreach \a/\t in {90/i,-30/j,210/k}{
    \node (\t) at (\a:1cm) {$\t$};
    \draw (\a-20:1cm)  arc (\a-20:\a-100:1cm);
  } 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** *(in response to the OP's comment)*

The `arrows.meta` library offers you the possibility to draw (almost) any arrow tip you may think of. To have the same look as that `Metapost` arrow tip, you can pass the following option to your environment:

```
-{Stealth[inset=0pt,length=4.5pt,angle'=35, round, bend]}
```

after loading the `arrows.meta` and `bending` libraries, of course.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[-{Stealth[inset=0pt,length=4.5pt,angle'=35,round,bend]}, scale=.7]
  \foreach \a/\t in {90/i,-30/j,210/k}{
    \node (\t) at (\a:1cm) {$\t$};
    \draw (\a-20:1cm)  arc (\a-20:\a-100:1cm);
  } 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is now how this looks:

[image]

Comment: There is a way to have the  ''arrow-head'' like in Thurston solution?

Answer (score 10):

Just for variety, you could also draw something like this using **smartdiagram**. The default produces rather more colourful diagrams with rather oversized nodes and undersized contents, for your purposes:

```
\smartdiagram[circular diagram:clockwise]{%
  $i$,$j$,$k$
}
```

[image: defaults]

However, the sizing can be quite easily dealt with:

```
\smartdiagramset{module minimum width=0, module minimum height=0, text width=1em, font=\large}
```

[image: resized]

as can the overly colourful appearance:

```
\smartdiagramset{uniform color list=gray!20 for 3 items, arrow color=gray, uniform arrow color=true}
```

[image: re-coloured]

Simply use `circular diagram`, omitting the `clockwise`, for the anti-clockwise direction:

[image: anticlockwise]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\smartdiagram[circular diagram:clockwise]{%
  $i$,$j$,$k$
}

\bigskip

\smartdiagramset{module minimum width=0, module minimum height=0, text width=1em, font=\large}

\smartdiagram[circular diagram:clockwise]{%
  $i$,$j$,$k$
}

\bigskip

\smartdiagramset{uniform color list=gray!20 for 3 items, arrow color=gray, uniform arrow color=true}

\smartdiagram[circular diagram:clockwise]{%
  $i$,$j$,$k$
}

\bigskip

\smartdiagram[circular diagram]{%
  $i$,$j$,$k$
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is very particular solution! I like it!

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution for LuaLatex using `luamplib` to make inline graphics.  The `mplibcode` environment creates an `hbox`, which I have centered on the baseline using `$\vcenter{...}$`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Schola}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Schola Math}
\begin{document}
\mplibcodeinherit{enable}
A circle going anti-clockwise $\vcenter{
\begin{mplibcode}
    path C; C = fullcircle scaled 32 rotated 90;
    beginfig(0);
    numeric a, b;
    for i=0 upto 2:
      a := 8/3 i;
      b := 8/3 (i+1);
      drawarrow subpath (a,b) of C
                cutbefore fullcircle scaled 16 shifted point a of C
                cutafter  fullcircle scaled 16 shifted point b of C;
                label(textext("$" & char (105+i) & "$"), point a of C);
    endfor
    endfig;
\end{mplibcode}}$ or clockwise $\vcenter{
\begin{mplibcode}
    beginfig(0);
    numeric a, b;
    for i=0 upto 2:
      a := 8/3 i;
      b := 8/3 (i+1);
      drawarrow subpath (b,a) of C
                cutbefore fullcircle scaled 16 shifted point b of C
                cutafter  fullcircle scaled 16 shifted point a of C;
                label(textext("$" & char (105+i) & "$"), point a of C);
    endfor
    endfig;
\end{mplibcode}}$ as you prefer.
\end{document}
```

### Notes

- The units are PostScript points 72 pt = 1in, 28.35 pt = 1cm.
- The predefined `fullcircle` path runs anticlockwise starting from "3 o'clock", so I rotated it here by 90° to make it start at the top.
- I've set `\mplibcodeinherit{enable}` so that the definition of path `C` can be reused in the second figure
- There are 8 points in a `fullcircle`, so the three points I needed were points 0, 8/3 and 16/3 of `C`.  Note that `point 24/3 of C` == `point 8 of C` == `point 0 of C`.
- `subpath (a,b) of C` returns the subsection of path from point a to point b, which I've shortened using the (slightly cumbersome) `cutbefore` and `cutafter` facilities.
- You can reverse a `subpath` by swapping the order of the arguments.
- `textext()` is a `luamplib` extension that allows you to build up the correct dynamic string.  Note that I've assumed that my font has the lower case alphabet in the standard ASCII positions.

For more on Metapost see: http://www.tug.org/metapost.html

For more on `luamplib` see: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/generic/luamplib

Comment: Your solution is awesome!

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (i) at (90:1cm) {i};
\node (j) at (-30:1cm) {j};
\node (k) at (210:1cm) {k};

\draw[-{[bend]>}] (i) to[out=0, in=60] (j);
\draw[-{[bend]>}] (j) to[out=-150, in=-30] (k);
\draw[-{[bend]>}] (k) to[out=120, in=-180] (i);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it just me or wouldn't the arrows look better if they were at bit more circular?

Comment: @daleif: No, you're right. It probably draws a spline curve, not a circular arc.

Comment: @daleif: You're right. I also wanted to produce AboAmmar's result but I couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

We can draw a similar diagram, ignoring the circle style and the equilateral triangle style and draw it upside down with the following tex code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=latex]
\node (a) {$i$};
\node (b) [above right of=a] {$j$};
\node (c) [above left of=a] {$k$};
\draw (a) -- (b);
\draw (b) -- (c);
\draw (c) -- (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

We can change `->` to `<-` for the counter-clockwise diagram. And we can change `>=latex` to `>=stealth` for another popular arrow tip.